# Downloading Images (inspect element shows link but available/downloadable source code doesn't)

Tags: c#, browser, webclient, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to download some pictures from a webpage. I can use "save image as" and "copy image url" in the browser and when I inspect the element it shows the url it has.
But when I download the source code of the page that contains the images it doesn't show up.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient()) // WebClient class inherits IDisposable
{
    client.DownloadFile("http://promos.sapo.pt/folheto/supermercado-minipreco-precos-arromba-8822-14-04-2014/", @"blablabla\Documents\teste\Folheto.xml");
}
```

The link that contains this is http://promos.sapo.pt/folheto/supermercado-continente-hiper-desconto-continente-modelo-bom-dia-6041-22-04-2014/

The available copy image url in page 3 links us to this

> http://thumbs.sapo.pt/?epic=UmcIIfWJDROWSrcm6vq8g1sZOWfojZpn4Qrxa+VFsPiYMYihtfHTtfiCL2pdzUndXkHqModrzDnULbnozGwpB/dGFKVgj9RT5LT0b93osuclCm4=&Q=80&errorpic=http%3A%2F%2Fpromos.sapo.pt%2Fimg%2Fthumb.png&W=1430&H=915

When I go to the developer tools of chrome and go to the network tab and I change from page 3 to page 4 the page 3 image shows this https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOPH4.png

Is it even possible to get the images links using c# ?

We have not so good solution that is to create the browser itself inside a form and press next page, but that's not viable since we need an "automatic" process.

Comment: Is the file downloaded? I guess it will be downloaded as html. Can you post the code you are using to read the downloaded file? What contents does the downloaded file has html or any error like 403 forbidden,etc.,?

Comment: The code i use to download the source code of the page is posted already the client.downloadfile()
Right now I don't have any code to read that specific source code because it doesn't contain anything related to the image page.

However i have a reading code of a more generic page to obtain all the promotion links.

Comment: XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"blablabla\Documents\teste\SourceCode.xml");
List<string> lista_links = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlNode _recNode in doc.GetElementsByTagName("link"))
{
    if (!_recNode.InnerText.Contains("rss"))
    {
        lista_links.Add(_recNode.InnerText);
    }
}

It does that after doing this

Comment: If you need the image link in C# then you should download the page that contains the image.

Comment: but that's the point the source code doesn't show its hidden, go to the website if you can.
We can only access the image link by using the browser "commands" save image as and copy image url.

I just don't see the point of them allowing these commands and hiding the source code needed so we can get the links automatically